# Decomposition of $s+\sqrt{-1}$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-1}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am trying to prove that in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-1}]$, every non-unit divisor of $s+\sqrt{-1}$ is not associate with an element of $\mathbb{Z}$ (which means, it is not a multiple of a unit with an element of $\mathbb{Z}$). I started with the decomposition $s+\sqrt{-1}=ab$ then
$$s^2+1=N(s+\sqrt{-1})=N(a)N(b)$$
and I am stuck here, I would appreciate hints!

Comment: Do you know that the units in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-1}]$ are $\pm 1$ and $\pm \sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: @J. W. Tanner yes

Comment: Hint: Clearly if $s=0$ then the expression is a unit, so the statement is vacuously true. Assume $s\ne 0$, and suppose $a$ is a non-unit divisor associate with an element of $\Z$ (so that $\pm a\in\Bbb{Z}$). What does that tell you about $b$?

Comment: @rogerl I just added my attpemt to the solution, do you think this is a valid proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found an answer: we just assume that $a,b$ are non-units and $b$ is associate with an element of $\mathbb{Z}$, that is $b=z$  or $b=\sqrt{-1}\cdot z$ for some $z\in\mathbb{Z}$. then we treat those two cases and we will get a contradicion, for example, if $b=z$, then:
$$s+\sqrt{-1}=ab=az\Rightarrow \frac{s}{z}+\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{z}$$
So, $\frac{1}{z}\in\mathbb{Z}$ as a coefficient of $\sqrt{-1}$, but the units in $\mathbb{Z}$ are $\pm 1$, then $b=z=\pm1$ which means that $b$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-1}]$ which is a contradiction to the assumption that $a,b$ are non-units. Is that solution valid?

Answer (score 0):

If $s+\sqrt{-1}=um$ with $m\in\Bbb Z$ and $u$ a unit, then
$$ s^2+1=N(s+\sqrt{-1})=N(u)N(m)=m^2$$
so
$$ 1=(m-s)(m+s)$$
which means that both $m+s$ and $m-s$ must be (the same) units in $\Bbb Z$. It follows that $s=0$.

Comment: what you have showed in here is that $s+\sqrt{-1}$ is not associated with any integer, how does it proves my statement?